# Activate foreign key constraints error in dataGrip

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, datagrip

I'm working with DataGrip and sqlite.
I have a table `suppliers` and another named `products` :

```
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nom TEXT,
siege_social TEXT);

CREATE TABLE Products (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nom TEXT,
prix REAL,
supplier INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (supplier) REFERENCES Suppliers(id)
);
```

I tried `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` to activate the foreign keys constraint as my teacher do.
However when I try to insert a product while having the supplier table empty, I get no error :

```sql
INSERT INTO Products values (1, "Lunettes Cobra", 30, 1);
```

[image]

I expected this : `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`

Do you know how I could make it raise an error for this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: @forpas I added the insert line I used, is that what you wanted?

Comment: No. I mean the full code that turns on foreign_keys and inserts the row.

Comment: Ok I recreated the table and I got the : 
`[2021-05-23 12:02:26] [19] [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY]  A foreign key constraint failed (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing pragma statement enables that setting only for currents session. Console and editor perform in different sessions.

Just go to advanced tab of the data source settings and set it there. It'll be applied for all sessions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@forpas asked for the whole code so I deleted all the existing tables and used this code :

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE Suppliers (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nom TEXT,
siege_social TEXT);

CREATE TABLE Products (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nom TEXT,
prix REAL,
supplier INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (supplier) REFERENCES Suppliers(id)
);
INSERT INTO Products values (2, "Lunettes Cobra", 30, 1);
```

And everything worked as expected.

```sql
[2021-05-23 12:02:26] [19] [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY]  A foreign key constraint failed (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed)
```

@forpas was right again, the fact that I created the table before activating the foreign_keys was not the problem. I used 2 console, one for creating the table and another for inserting values. I only activated `foreign_keys` in the first one. I thought it was activated in the database but it's console related.

Comment: The is no problem if you turn on foreign_keys after the creation of the table as long as you do it before the insertion of the new row and in the same transaction.

Comment: Yes I you're right I was turning on foreign_keys in a console and inserting rows from another